# Выборочное подключение элементов из отдельного файла на страницу

Tags: php

В файле `/includes/advert.php` имеется несколько рекламных блоков

```
echo 'рекблок1';
echo 'рекблок2';
echo 'рекблок3';
...
```

Для каждой страницы требуется выводить разное кол-во блоков.
Подскажите, как можно вывести на страницу, например, `/content.php` блоки 1 и 3 используя конструкцию `include()` либо что-нибудь похожее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед `include()` на странице укажите сколько (и какие) блоки выводить.

Внутри `advert.php` вставьте логику для отображение указанных блоков.

Страница:

```
$showBlocks = Array(1,3);
include("/includes/advert.php");
```

А внутри `advert.php` что-то типа такого:

```
$blocks = Array("рекблок1", "рекблок2", "рекблок3");
foreach($showBlocks as $shBlock) {
    echo $blocks[$shBlock-1];
}
```

Понятно, что надо добавить еще проверки на наличие блоков и т.д. Но как примерное направление, думаю, мой ответ подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните данные в файле XML или JSON. Потом подгружаете этот файл и вытаскиваете нужные данные.
Еще можно просто хранить все в базе и подтягивать из базы нужные обьявления на нужных страницах.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше создайте табличку adBlocks в БД.
Потом с нее выбирайте `SELECT` запросом свои блоки и с помощью функции `$blocks[rand(0, count($blocks)-1)]` или `$blocks[array_rand($blocks, 1)]` рандомно выбирайте блок и отображайте с него данные.
Вот к примеру:

```
$blocks = [
 [
    'title' => 'Lorem ipsum',
    'img'   => 'img/block_1.png'
 ],
 [
    'title' => 'Dolor sit',
    'img'   => 'img/block_2.png'
 ],
 [
    'title' => 'Amet',
    'img'   => 'img/block_3.png'
 ]
];

$select = $blocks[array_rand($blocks, 1)];

echo "<div>{$select['title']}";
echo "<p>";
echo "<img src='{$select['img']}' width='64' height='96' title='{$select['title']}'>"
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
```

Чуть позже выложу песочку с примером где-нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Лучше каждый блок пусть лежит в своём отдельном файле. Чтобы не грузить зря всё, но показывать лишь часть.

Называйте файлы блоков по единому стандарту, напр., в папке `/includes/`: `/block1.php`, `block2.php`, .. `block99.php`.

Менеджер реклам `/includes/advert.php` подключайте всегда. Предполагается, что он лежит в той же папке, что и рекламные блоки. В нём определите ф-ю показа:

```
function showBlocks($blocks) {
    if( is_array( $blocks) {
        foreach( $blocks AS $n) showBlockN( $n);
    } else if( $n = intval($blocks)) {
        showBlockN( $n);
    }
}

function showBlockN( $n) {
    $filename = __DIR__ . "/block" . $n . ".php";
    if( is_readable($filename)) include $filename;
}
```

И из любой страницы вызывайте показ блоков либо с массивом:

```
showBlocks([1,3]);
```

либо с единственным значением:

```
showBlocks(3);
```